# How to create constant C like struct objects under a namespace in Python

Tags: python, object, static, constants

I want to create constant objects of a class that I can use again and again in other classes and functions

```
# Simple C like struct
class data:
  def __init__(self,a,b)
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

# Constant objects in a namespace ??
class DATA_CONSTANTS:
  DATA1 = data(0,0)
  DATA2 = data(3,5)
  DATA3 = data(43, 23)
```

If I now want to use DATA_CONSTANTS.DATA1, will it be created on first call or everytime I refer to this object ?

What I am looking for is something like in C++ where you create constant objects in a global or given namespace that can be reused as a constant object with fully qualified name say DATA_CONSTANTS::DATA1 or DATA_CONSTANTS::DATA2 etc.

However I am not sure what I am doing above is a pythonic way to accomplish the same in Python. Is this correct ?

Comment: "If I now want to use DATA_CONSTANTS.DATA1, will it be created on first call or everytime I refer to this object ?" The object, a class, is created once as a result of the class definition statement. No other object is ever created, why would it be?

Comment: Python doesn't really have user-defined constants, btw, only conventions

Comment: I've used enums for module-wide constants. https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Comment: you an also uses a `DATA_CONSTANTS = types.SimpleNameSpace(DATA1 = data(0,0), DATA2 = data(3,5), DATA3 = data(43, 23))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared in the upper level of a class are [class variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), and are only created once at the site that they're declared, then they remain constants. You can see this for yourself:

```py
def calc_value():
    print("computed the value")
    return 1

class Foo:
    my_var = calc_value()

print(Foo.my_var + Foo.my_var)
# prints "computed the value" then 2
```

Comment: Given the OPs background in C++, I think we need to be precise about the word *declared*. Variables/attributes are *never declared* in Python. The come into existence when they are assigned to. A class definition statement is *executable code*, essentially, elaborate syntactic sugar over a call to the `type` constructor, e.g. `Foo = type('Foo', (object,), {'my_var':calc_value()})`. In that respect, the OP needs to abandon a lot of the thinking that comes from a very nominally typed, relatively low-level, and statically compiled language.

Comment: So, again to be overly pedantic, "are only created once at the program start" is misleading, classes are created whenvever a class definitioon statement runs, or directly using various means (like the manual call to the `type` constructor above). You can put a class definition in a loop, in a function, etc